# How can I return an exit code from a PowerShell module's function without exiting the shell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.4

I need to run my PowerShell module's PowerShell function from a Bash shell. The PowerShell function is supposed to return an exit code for the Bash shell to evaluate.

However, when I write:

```
function f
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  ( [Parameter()][string]$Test
  )

  process { exit 1 }
}
```

… in `Test.ps1`, using this in a PowerShell module (`Test.psm1`) like this:

```
. .\Test.ps1
```

… and have it run in PowerShell like this:

```
Import-Module .\Test.psm1
f ''
```

… the PowerShell console is getting closed. This is not what I want to happen.

How can I return an exit code from PowerShell module's function without terminating the current PowerShell session?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  In order for Bash to receive an exit code from Powershell, Powershell must exit.

Comment: Try replacing the "exit" keyword in your example with "return". I agree with @asm. We need more clarity of what you're trying to do

Comment: Yes, PowerShell must exit, yet it is supposed to return an exit code, which it doesn't. For the reasoning behind this, see: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4870#issuecomment-2002504789

Comment: This issue has been solved here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me provide some **background information**, to complement your own answer:

- *Exit codes* are a *system-level* concept relating to *processes*: a process can signal the success status of its invocation to the calling process by way of an integer value, with - by widely observed convention - `0` signaling success, and any *nonzero* value a failure condition.<sup>[1]</sup>
- [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords#exit), optionally with a given *exit code*, is only used in two scenarios in PowerShell:

  - When executed *outside a script file*: to *exit the entire PowerShell process*.
  - To exit a *script file*. Whether that exit code is *relayed* as the exit code of the entire PowerShell process depends on how PowerShell was invoked (see below).
  - Whether or not `exit` is called from *inside a function* is incidental to its effect; that is, if the function happens to be called from *outside* a script file, the PowerShell process is exited; from *inside* a script file, that script alone is exited.
  - In PowerShell's own error handling, exit codes play only a *very limited role*. The closest analog to an exit code in PowerShell is the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1), which is a *Boolean* value (`$true` or `$false`) that *abstractly* indicates whether *any* error was reported by the most recently executed statement:<sup>[2]</sup>

    - For calls to PowerShell-native commands *except script files*, the occurrence of a (statement-)terminating error or *anything* having been written to PowerShell's error [stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) (i.e. a *non-terminating* error) is what causes `$?` to reflect `$false`. While the latter is consistently true for *binary* cmdlets, in *functions* it only applies to [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions that explicitly use `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` or `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` - see [GitHub issue #3629](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3629).
    - For calls to *external programs* and *script files*, it is a *nonzero exit code* (as reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode))<sup>[3]</sup> that sets `$?` to `$false`.
- To communicate an exit code from PowerShell code to a *calling process* - such as in CI/CD scenarios - you must therefore ensure that calls to the PowerShell *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7) relay the desired exit code as the CLI's *own* process exit code, which is achieved in one of two ways:

  - If all your code runs in a *script file* (`.ps1`), use the `-File` (`-f`) CLI parameter and ensure that your script file uses an `exit` call with the desired exit code, which PowerShell then automatically passes through as its own exit code.

    - E.g., if your `foo.ps1` script exits with `exit 5`, the following CLI call will report `5` as its exit code:

      ```bash
      pwsh -File foo.ps1
      ```
    - On Unix-like platforms, this mechanism is *implicitly* used if you create an executable shell script with a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).
  - If you must pass *PowerShell commands*, i.e. a piece of PowerShell code to the CLI, use the latter's `-Command` (`-c`) parameter, in which case PowerShell's own exit code is determined as follows:

    - The success status of the *last statement executed*, as reflected in `$?`, is mapped to exit code `0` or `1`: if `$?` is `$true`, the exit code is `0`, `1` otherwise; however, by using an explicit `exit` statement as the - by definition - last one, you *can* control the specific exit code.
  - In case a(n unhandled) *script-terminating* (fatal) error occurs, such as via [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw), the exit code is `1` in *both* invocation scenarios.
- Focusing on your specific scenario:

  - A *function* generally shouldn't be concerned with signaling a process exit code - except, perhaps, if it is known to execute *as part of a script file* and is designed to act on behalf of that file as whole.
  - Generally, functions should signal failure to their (of necessity in-session) caller in *PowerShell* terms, which - if the function call happens to be the last statement executed in a `-Command` (`-c`) CLI invocation - translates to a process exit code of `1`.

    - Unfortunately, there is no way to *directly and abstractly* signal failure from a PowerShell function: `$?` is set solely based on whether `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` or `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` was explicitly called, which (a) is only an option from *advanced* functions, as noted, and (b) invariably cause *error-stream output*, which the *caller* would need to silence to prevent it from surfacing.

      - Remedying this limitation by allowing functions to set `$?` *directly* for the caller in the future has been *green-lit*, but is *yet to be implemented* - see [GitHub issue #10917](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917#issuecomment-550550490)
  - However, you can use a `throw` statement from inside a function to both stop execution of the function instantly and to signal a severe error to the caller - without directly exiting an *interactive* session, as would happen if you used `exit` and called the function from outside a script (as shown in your question).

    - In a CLI call, if the code passed to `-Command` doesn't handle the resulting *script-terminating* error, the CLI reports `1` as the exit code, as noted; however, this will cause an *error message* to surface as well.
    - To (optionally) avoid an error message and report a *specific* exit code, you could pass the desired exit code as an argument to `throw`, let the in-session caller catch it via [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally), and report it as the CLI's exit code via an `exit` call in the `catch` block:

      ```bash
       # Reports exit code 5.
       pwsh -c 'function foo { throw 5 }; try { foo } catch { exit $_.TargetObject }'
      ```

---

<sup>[1] The permitted range of integer values depends on the host platform: windows permits `[int]` values (signed 32-bit integers), which on Unix-like platforms you're limited to `[byte]` values (unsigned 8-bit integers). In cross-platform code, it is therefore best to limit exit codes to between `0` and `255`, inclusively.</sup>

<sup>[2] `$?` is *implicitly* also used with `&&` and `||`, the [pipeline-chaining operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators).</sup>

<sup>[3] Strictly speaking, a script-file's execution is considered successful if it terminates with `exit 0` (which is the same as just `exit`) or exits *implicitly* (even if errors occurred *inside* the script); only if `exit` is actually used is `$LASTEXITCODE` set; thus, `$LASTEXITCODE` may reflect an *incidental* value afterwards, such as from an *earlier*, unrelated external-program call, which is problematic - see [GitHub issue #11712](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11712). Fortunately, however, `$?` is set correctly in all cases, and script-file execution therefore also works with `&&` and `||`.</sup>

Comment: Wow..! Thanks so much for sharing this very detailed and exploratory information!  — I wasn't aware of the fact that `Write-Error -ErrorAction Continue` would also set the exit code. In this case I could even have omitted the `exit` call then.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @AxD; my pleasure. `Write-Error -ErrorAction Continue` would only set the exit code in a `-Command` invocation if it is the _last_ statement executed, outside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my question:

https://jhoneill.github.io/powershell/2019/08/21/ExitThrowReturnEtc.html

> If I run PowerShell –Command "MyScript.ps1" the rules don’t change. PowerShell returns an exit code of 1 or 0 depending on whether the last (only) command threw an error. If the script ends with exit 123 then $LASTEXITCODE is 123 in that instance of PowerShell and in that instance something else can see that exit code.
> Then when that instance of PowerShell exits, it follows the standard rules – the Exit code from the script is lost.